# GTK3 and C# - How to load Composite Template Widgets

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk3, gtk#

I am trying to use composite templates with C# and GTK# 3.0. I understand them but I cannot seem to declare it properly.

I first attempted to add the composite template to my main glade project, but if I declare a new builder with that glade project, it states that it was not expecting a composite template, so I assumed that the actual widget has to be in it's own glade file, which is ok.

However, I don't know how to declare the composite template with C#. Can anyone let me know how to declare the composite template so I can use it?

So generally

```
Builder Gui = new Builder();
Gui.AddFromFile("togglebuttons.xml");
Gui.Autoconnect(this);
Gtk.Application.Run();
```

works for non composite templates, but what is the way to load a composite template widget?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and find a solution.
1. I use VALA to use a Template and make it visible to Glade.
2. I Implement the control with gtk-sharp using an feature version where "TypeNameAttribute" avail!

All based on this...
https://blogs.gnome.org/tvb/2013/05/29/composite-templates-lands-in-vala/

Hope this help a little...